# oauth Handshake error using twitteR in R

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, rcurl

I have been trying to download some tweets from using the tweeteR package in R

The code for my oauth credentials is

```
cred<-AuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
consumerSecret=consumerSecret,requestURL=reqURL,accessURL=accessURL,authURL=authURL)
```

When i try to run the following for handshake

```
cred$handshake(cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL","cacert.pem",package="RCurl"))
```

I am getting this error

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Could not resolve host: api.twitter.com; No data record of requested type
```

I am running the code in a windows machine. (I have included the code for downloading cacert.pem)

Answer (score 4):

I worked out the solution for this, for people who are behind a proxy they have to set the proxy options in RCurl too(setting the proxy for the R is not enough). This command works

```
options( RCurlOptions = list(verbose = TRUE,proxy = "host:port"))
```